# Is there a SCORM RTE in .NET?

Tags: scorm, scorm2004, scorm1.2

Is there any SCORM RTE in .NET exists?
I have gone through DotNetNuke but found it unfriendly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking solely for a .NET SCORM RTE and not a full blown LMS than Rustici Software makes a .NET SCORM RTE available at http://scorm.com/scorm-solved/scorm-engine/

Answer (score 0):

If you need a good LMS starting point then try the Sharepoint Learning Environment at slk.codeplex.com. There is an RTE in there, as well as many other tools for a full SCORM environment.

Bear in mind that a SCORM RTE on its own may not be very helpful. You need to consider matters like persisting it, how and where you are going to do this. And without the rest of the SCORM environment ( particularly SN ) then you will not have proper SCORM compliance.

If you need it simply for running certain SCORM packages, then this should do you fine.

Comment: This link slc.codeplex.com leads to "Simple WPF Line Chart", it has nothing common with SCORM.